# MySql gem installation failure

Tags: mysql, ruby, gem

I'm attempting to install a mysql gem on my workstation with this command

gem install mysql-2.8.1.gem

output :

```
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql-2.8.1.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -llibmysql... yes
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1
 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/ge
m_make.out
```

so it previously had trouble finding "libmysqllib" untill i copied the file into the same directory as the gem I am manually installing.

I'm behind a proxy, so I have to download the *.gem files and install from there.

```
Running XP Sp3
MySQL version : 5.1.53
Ruby Version 1.8.7

Gem list :

actionmailer (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
actionpack (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activerecord (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activeresource (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
activesupport (2.3.5, 2.3.4)
hoe (2.7.0)
json_pure (1.4.6)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rake-compiler (0.7.5)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
```

Please help.

Kind Regards,
Noel.

Answer (score 0):

**You're missing some compile-time dependencies.** Things to check

- Do you have the mysql dev files installed e.g. on Ubuntu this is libmysqlclient15-dev
- Are the ruby1.8.7 dev files installed e.g. ruby1.8-dev Ubuntu

You really shouldn't need to copy the the lib. That would indicate that you probably don't have the mysqlclient libs installed


Hope that helps!

Chris

Comment: Already downloaded and installed from mysql.com "mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-win32.msi", which is the link for "MySQL Connectors/C (libmysql)" I think your right about missing that lib, but I have the file on my pc, hence why i copied it.         Could not find the ruby dev files you mentioned, I'm on windows xp so I used 'ruby installer' to install ruby on my windows box "http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/".